# Compute limit of Cov(X, Y)

Tags: probability

Let $X$ ~ $N(0,1)$ and $Y = cX$.
Compute $\lim_{c\to0^+}Cov(X,Y)$.

I've computed:

$\lim_{c\to0^+}Cov(X,Y) = \lim_{c\to0^+} E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad= \lim_{c\to0^+} cE(X^2)-c(E(X))^2$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad= \lim_{c\to0^+} cVar(X)$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad= \lim_{c\to0^+} c$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad= 0$

Similarly, $\lim_{c\to0^-}Cov(X,Y) = 0$.

Is this right?

Comment: The calculation is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yes, because also the Covariance between a variable and a constant is zero (they react fully independent).

When c is positive or negative, X and cX would be perfectly positively/negatively correlated, but for $0$ it should be independent. I see no discontinuity so the limit should equal $0$.